# In each part, find a basis for the given subspace ofR 3 , and state its dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

guys I gotta be honest, I've taken notes on everything in the last two sections for this but I'm not sure how to find a basis for a subspace that is a lone plane/line etc.. a full explanation would really help..

all I can think of is adding two random planes to (a), taking the determinent and if its not 0 find out its a basis for R3? but I have a feeling thats not right, also is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

I'll demonstrate with the first one. I like to think of basis vectors via parameters/constraints/equations. In your first problem, we have

$$3x-2y+5z = 0.$$

Or equivalently,

$$5z = -3x+2y \quad\Longrightarrow \quad z = -\frac{3}{5}x+\frac{2}{5}y.$$

So what does this tell us? We have two independent values, $x$ and $y$, which uniquely determine $z$. So any vector on the plane is of the form $(x,y,-\frac{3}{5}x+\frac{2}{5}y)$.

To extract basis vectors, what you want to do is to collect your parameters. So in the above, we have two parameters: $x$ and $y$. We can collect them in two different vectors:

$$(x,y,-\frac{3}{5}x+\frac{2}{5}y) = \left(1,0,-\frac{3}{5}\right)x+\left(0,1,\frac{2}{5}\right)y.$$

Your basis vectors are then the separated vectors $\left(1,0,-\frac{3}{5}\right)$ and $\left(0,1,\frac{2}{5}\right)y.$ Can you see how to do the others by following this train of logic?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** for (d).  The subspace is$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}$
$$\eqalign{S
  &=\{\,(a,b,c)\mid b=a+c,\ a,b,c\in\Bbb R\,\}\cr
  &=\{\,(a,a+c,c)\mid a,c\in\Bbb R\,\}\cr
  &=\{\,a(1,1,0)+c(0,1,1)\mid a,c\in\Bbb R\,\}\ .\cr}$$
Now, a basis is a linearly independent spanning set.  Can you find two vectors $\\u,\\v$ such that every vector in $S$ is a scalar times $\\u$ plus a scalar times $\\v$?  Can you then check that these vectors are linearly independent?

Answer (score 0):

for the (i) $$\left(x,y,x\right)=\left(x,\dfrac{3x+5z}{2},z\right)=x\left(1,\dfrac{3}{2},0\right)+z\left(0,\dfrac{5}{2},1\right)$$

Hence basis is $\{\left(1,\dfrac{3}{2},0\right),\left(0,\dfrac{5}{2},1\right)\}$. Hence the dimension is $2$.

For (ii), $$\left(x,y,z\right)=x\left(1,1,0\right)+z\left(0,0,1\right)$$Hence basis is $\{\left(1,1,0\right),\left(0,0,1\right)\}$.

The rest can be done like this